# Android contacts - Retrieved Android contacts, how to put them in a simple ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor

for part of my application I require a list of all contacts (with phone numbers) to be displayed when the option is selected.

Here is the activity which is called when the button is pressed:

```
package com.example.prototype01;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;

public class nominateContactsActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nominatecontactslayout);
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        String contactName, contactTelNumber = "";
        String contactID;
        c.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
            contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            contactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactID },null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    contactTelNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                } 
            }
            Log.i("name ", contactName + " ");
            Log.i("number ", contactTelNumber + " ");
            c.moveToNext();

        }
    }
    }
```

As you can see, this code returns the Name and Phone Number of all contacts stored on the handset. Currently, these are simply echoed to logcat. I can't seem to work out how to list these items in a listview instead, with just the name and number displayed. I have followed a couple of tutorials to no avail and so reluctantly i seek your kind assistance. I say reluctantly as I'm sure this question has been answered many times, I just can't seem to apply the solutions to my code!

Thank you in advance!!

Kind Regards,
Antwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to adapt what you already have. I added comments before everything I changed to explain along the way:

```
public class nominateContactsActivity extends Activity {
    // Add a list to keep all the "name: number" strings
    private List<String> mNameNumber = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nominatecontactslayout);
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        String contactName, contactTelNumber = "";
        String contactID;

        // You only need to find these indices once
        int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        int hasNumberIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);


        // This is simpler than calling getCount() every iteration
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            contactName = c.getString(nameIndex);
            contactID = c.getString(idIndex);

            // If this is an integer ask for an integer
            if (c.getInt(hasNumberIndex)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contactID },null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    contactTelNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    // Store the "name: number" string in our list
                    mNameNumber.add(contactName + ": " + contactTelNumber);
                } 
            }
        }

        // Find the ListView, create the adapter, and bind them
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mNameNumber);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it recommended to use CursorLoaders, or is that not applicable in this context?

Comment: @aamit915 CursorLoaders were added in API 11 and they are included in the backwards compatibility libraries to some extent. But if the author only wants to run this on pre-API 11 devices, they are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do to put contacts in a listView

In your activity:

```
private ListView mContactsListView;
private ListContactItemAdapter mContactsListAdapter;

this.mContactsListAdapter = new ListContactItemAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_row);

// after doing setContentView, assuming you have defined a listview in your layout file
this.mContactsListView= (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);
// You may want to create a custom adapter, which I wrote below for showing you example
this.mContactsListView.setAdapter(this.mContactsListAdapter);

for (/* each contact */) {

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.name = contactName;
    contact.number = contactNumber;

    this.mContactsListAdapter.add(contact);
}

// In order to refresh your list and make data appear
this.mContactsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Of course in my example you need a model object containing contact data:

```
public class Contact  {

public String name;
public String number;

}
```

And this could be your custom adapter using the Contact class above:

```
public class ListContactItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

private int mLineLayout;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public ListContactItemAdapter(Context pContext, int pLineLayout) {
    super(pContext, pLineLayout);

    this.mLineLayout = pLineLayout;
    this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) pContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView contactName;
    TextView contactNumber;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pPosition, View pView, ViewGroup pParent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (pView == null) {

        pView = this.mInflater.inflate(this.mLineLayout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.contactName = (TextView) pView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        holder.contactNumber = (TextView) pView.findViewById(R.id.contactNumber);

        pView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) pView.getTag();
    }

    Contact contact = getItem(pPosition);
    if (contact != null) {

        holder.contactName.setText(contact.name);
        holder.contactNumber.setText(contact.number);
    }

    return pView;
}
```

}

For that example your need a layout to define rows, of your listview. This could be a contact_row.xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:text="Contact name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contactName"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:text="number"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I didn't try but this should work. And anyway, I hope it will make you understand how listviews basically work.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your kind assistance, I know have a fully working application after hours of trying and tearing out clumps of hair!!

Thank you so very much

Comment: Hi There, after a bit of testing I appear to have missed something...

When I scroll down the contacts list, the tick box becomes un-ticked and the 'new' top position becomes ticked - if you see what I mean, rather difficult to explain without seeing!

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Items are recycled while scrolling, so your tick box (checked) is moved around with the recycling process. You should care about the position of your tick boxes, keep track of checked positions, something like that, and manage the tick programmatically inside getView.. or if you want to change your approach by using a CheckedTextView, maybe this answer I made (a long time ago) can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028167/checkable-listview-cursor-data-independent-checkbox/12029688#12029688

Comment: Brilliant thank you, have adapted your code for my application, however, I can't get my head around the cursor......in my previous example (adapted from the above recursive call, using a while loop) It was possible to only select contacts with phone numbers....I can't seem to fit this into your version...Think i need more coffee!! Thank you so much for your help though.